# .NET Application Updater Component 405 error

Tags: .net, auto-update

I'm trying to use the .NET Application Updater Component on a form following the example from the official page: http://windowsclient.net/articles/appupdater.aspx

I get a 405 error from the application: "The auto-update of this application failed with the following error message: Download of a new update from 'http://localhost/try/SampleApp_ServerSetup/2.0.0.0/' failed with the network error: Service remote error 405) Method not allowed

I've tried:
- changing the url in UpdateVersion.xml to 'http://localhost/try/SampleApp_ServerSetup/2.0.0.0'

The iis is configured to allow directory browsing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Im having a simmilar issue to this. I cant even read the update version.xml file. Get the same 405 error

Comment: I had to use an open library: NAppUpdate (http://www.code972.com/blog/2010/08/nappupdate-application-auto-update-framework-for-dotnet/)
Give it a try

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and the following fixed it:

In WebDav properties of root website, set 'Allow  Anonymous Property Queries' = TRUE

Comment: I had this on windows 7 and found it was webdav not being enabled correctly on my localhost (just playing at the moment) and this post [link](http://www.slickit.ca/2009/07/webdav-on-windows-7.html) (the first part on enabling it worked perfectly